# Skanda slokas missing in Sanskrit

Tags: mahabharata, translation-request

I am looking for Sanskrit shlokas for the below [sections in English](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03230.htm).

Starting from:

> Vaisampayana continued, "Thus addressed by the Pandava in that assembly of Rishis, the worshipful Markandeya of high ascetic merit replied, 'Agneya (Son of Agni),...........(rest of the paragraphs)

And, the next paragraph in the translation:

> Thou art devoted to Brahma, begotten of Brahma, and versed in the mysteries of Brahma. Thou art called Brahmasaya,.......(rest of the paragraph)

The [Sanskrit version](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs03221.htm) of this is here, but it is missing the verses for above paragraphs.

Any other sources? Please help.

Comment: FYI, the English and Sanskrit versions of sacred-text website are not same... Sanskrit is critical edition (after removing lot of shlokas)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find those verses missing from the BORI Critical Edition of Mahābhārata, on the [GRETIL](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil.html) website:

> http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/2_epic/mbh/mbh_03_u.htm
>
> % Mahabharata: Aranyakaparvan
> % Electronic text (C) Bhandarkar Oriental Research Institute,
> % Pune, India, 1999
>
> % On the basis of the text entered by Muneo Tokunaga et al.,
> % revised by John Smith, Cambridge, et al.
>
> 03,221.080d@022_0000   yudhiṣṭhira uvāca
> 03,221.080d@022_0001   bhagavañ śrotum icchāmi nāmāny asya mahātmanaḥ
>
> 03,221.080d@022_0002   vaiśaṃpāyana uvāca
> 03,221.080d@022_0002   triṣu lokeṣu yāny asya vikhyātāni dvijottama
> 03,221.080d@022_0003   ity uktaḥ pāṇḍaveyena mahātmā ṛṣisaṃnidhau
>
> 03,221.080d@022_0004   mārkaṇḍeya uvāca
> 03,221.080d@022_0004   uvāca bhagavāṃs tatra mārkaṇḍeyo mahātapāḥ
> 03,221.080d@022_0005   **āgneyaś** caiva **skandaś** ca **dīptakīrtir** anāmayaḥ
> 03,221.080d@022_0006   mayūraketur dharmātmā bhūteśo mahiṣārdanaḥ
> 03,221.080d@022_0007   kāmajit kāmadaḥ kāntaḥ satyavāg bhuvaneśvaraḥ
> 03,221.080d@022_0008   śiśuḥ śīghraḥ śuciś caṇḍo dīptavarṇaḥ śubhānanaḥ
> 03,221.080d@022_0009   amoghas tv anagho raudraḥ priyaś candrānanas tathā
> 03,221.080d@022_0010   dīptaśaktiḥ praśāntātmā bhadrakṛt kūṭamohanaḥ
> 03,221.080d@022_0011   ṣaṣṭhīpriyaś ca dharmātmā pavitro mātṛvatsalaḥ
> 03,221.080d@022_0012   kanyābhartā vibhaktaś ca svāheyo revatīsutaḥ
> 03,221.080d@022_0013   prabhur netā viśākhaś ca naigameyaḥ suduścaraḥ
> 03,221.080d@022_0014   suvrato lalitaś caiva bālakrīḍanakapriyaḥ
> 03,221.080d@022_0015   khacārī brahmacārī ca śūraḥ śaravaṇodbhavaḥ
> 03,221.080d@022_0016   viśvāmitrapriyaś caiva devasenāpriyas tathā
> 03,221.080d@022_0017   vāsudevapriyaś caiva priyaḥ priyakṛd eva tu
> 03,221.080d@022_0018   nāmāny etāni divyāni kārttikeyasya yaḥ paṭhet
> 03,221.080d@022_0019   svargaṃ kīrtiṃ dhanaṃ caiva sa labhen nātra saṃśayaḥ
>
> 03,221.080d@022_0019   mārkaṇḍeya uvāca
> 03,221.080d@022_0020   stoṣyāmi devair ṛṣibhiś ca juṣṭaṃ
> 03,221.080d@022_0021   śaktyā guhaṃ nāmabhir aprameyam
> 03,221.080d@022_0022   ṣaḍānanaṃ śaktidharaṃ suvīraṃ
> 03,221.080d@022_0023   nibodha caitāni kurupravīra
> 03,221.080d@022_0024   **brahmaṇyo** vai **brahmajo** **brahmavic** ca
> 03,221.080d@022_0025   brahmeśayo brahmavatāṃ variṣṭhaḥ
> 03,221.080d@022_0026   brahmapriyo brāhmaṇasavratī tvaṃ
> 03,221.080d@022_0027   brahmajño vai brāhmaṇānāṃ ca netā
> 03,221.080d@022_0028   svāhā svadhā tvaṃ paramaṃ pavitraṃ
> 03,221.080d@022_0029   mantrastutas tvaṃ prathitaḥ ṣaḍarciḥ
> 03,221.080d@022_0030   saṃvatsaras tvam ṛtavaś ca ṣaḍ vai
> 03,221.080d@022_0031   māsārdhamāsāv ayanaṃ diśaś ca
> 03,221.080d@022_0032   tvaṃ puṣkarākṣas tv aravindvaktraḥ
> 03,221.080d@022_0033   sahasravaktro 'si sahasrabāhuḥ
> 03,221.080d@022_0034   tvaṃ lokapālaḥ paramaṃ haviś ca
> 03,221.080d@022_0035   tvaṃ bhāvanaḥ sarvasurāsurāṇām
> 03,221.080d@022_0036   tvam eva senādhipatiḥ pracaṇḍaḥ
> 03,221.080d@022_0037   prabhur vibhuś cāpy atha śatrujetā
> 03,221.080d@022_0038   sahasrabhūs tvaṃ dharaṇī tvam eva
> 03,221.080d@022_0039   sahasratuṣṭiś ca sahasrabhuk ca
> 03,221.080d@022_0040   sahasraśīrṣas tvam anantarūpaḥ
> 03,221.080d@022_0041   sahasrapāt tvaṃ guha śaktidhārī
> 03,221.080d@022_0042   gaṅgāsutas tvaṃ svamatena deva
> 03,221.080d@022_0043   svāhāmahīkṛttikānāṃ tathaiva
> 03,221.080d@022_0044   tvaṃ krīḍase ṣaṇmukha kukkuṭena
> 03,221.080d@022_0045   yatheṣṭanānāvidhakāmarūpī
> 03,221.080d@022_0046   dīkṣāsi somo marutaḥ sadaiva
> 03,221.080d@022_0047   dharmo 'si vāyur acalendra indraḥ
> 03,221.080d@022_0048   sanātanānām api śāśvatas tvaṃ
> 03,221.080d@022_0049   prabhuḥ prabhūṇām api cogradhanvā
> 03,221.080d@022_0050   ṛtasya kartā ditijāntakas tvaṃ
> 03,221.080d@022_0051   jetā ripūṇāṃ pravaraḥ surāṇām
> 03,221.080d@022_0052   sūkṣmaṃ tapas tat paramaṃ tvam eva
> 03,221.080d@022_0053   parāvarajño 'si parāvaras tvam
> 03,221.080d@022_0054   dharmasya kāmasya parasya caiva
> 03,221.080d@022_0055   tvattejasā kṛtsnam idaṃ mahātman
> 03,221.080d@022_0056   vyāptaṃ jagat sarvasurapravīra
> 03,221.080d@022_0057   śaktyā mayā saṃstuta lokanātha
> 03,221.080d@022_0058   namo 'stu te dvādaśanetrabāho
> 03,221.080d@022_0059   ataḥ paraṃ vedmi gatiṃ na te 'ham
> 03,221.080d@022_0060   skandasya ya idaṃ vipraḥ paṭhej janma samāhitaḥ
> 03,221.080d@022_0061   śrāvayed brāhmaṇebhyo yaḥ śṛṇuyād vā dvijeritam
> 03,221.080d@022_0062   dhanam āyur yaśo dīptaṃ putrāñ śatrujayaṃ tathā
> 03,221.080d@022_0063   sa puṣṭituṣṭī saṃprāpya skandasālokyam āpnuyāt

There are also present in the [Southern Recension of the Mahābhārata](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mbhK/mahabharata-k-03-itx.html) (Kumbhakonam Edition):

> **3.233. adhyAyaH 233**
>
> mArkaNDeyena yudhiShThirAya skandanAmnAM kIrtanam ..
>
> 3-233-0   (25133)
>
> yudhiShThira uvAcha. 3-233-0x   (2579)
>
> bhagava~nshrotumichChAmi nAmAni cha mahAtmanaH.
> tariShu lokeShu yAnyasya vikhyAtAni dvijottama .. 3-233-1   (25134)
>
> vaishampAyana uvAcha. 3-233-2x   (2580)
>
> ityuktaH pANDaveyena mahAtmA R^iShisannidhau.
> uvAcha bhagavAMstatra mArkaNDeyo mahAtapAH .. 3-233-2   (25135)
> **Ageyashchaiva skanadashcha dIptakIrtiranAmayaH**.
> mayUraketurdharmAtmA bhUtesho mahiShArdanaH .. 3-233-3   (25136)
> kAmajitkAmadaH kAntaH satyavAgbhuvaneshvaraH.
> shishuH shIghraH shuchishchaNDo dIptavarNaH shubhAnanaH .. 3-233-4   (25137)
> amoghastvanagho raudraH priyashchandrAnanastathA.
> dIptashaktiH prashAntAtmA nadrakukkuTamohanaH .. 3-233-5   (25138)
> ShaShThIpriyashcha dharmAtmA pavitro mAtR^ivatsalaH.
> kanyAbhartA vibhaktashcha svAheyo revatIsutaH .. 3-233-6   (25139)
> prabhurnetA vishAkhashcha naigameyaH sudushcharaH.
> suvrato lalitashchaivabAlakrIDanakapriyaH .. 3-233-7   (25140)
> khachArI brahmachArI cha shUraH sharavaNodbhavaH.
> vishvAmitrapriyashchaiva devasenApriyastathA.
> vAsudevapriyashchaiva priyaH priyakR^ideva tu .. 3-233-8   (25141)
> nAmAnyetAni divyAni kArtikeyasya yaH paThet.
> svargaM kIrtiM dhanaM chaiva sa labhennAtra saMshayaH .. 3-233-9   (25142)
>
> mArkaNDeya uvAcha. 3-233-10x   (2581)
>
> stoShyAmi devairR^iShibhishcha juShTaM
> shaktyA guhaMnAmabhiraprameyam.
> ShaDAnanaM shaktidharaM suvIraM
> nibodha chaitAni kurupravIra .. 3-233-10   (25143)
> **brahmaNyo vai brahamajo brahmavichcha**
> brahmeshayo brahmavatAMvariShThaH.
> brahmapriyo brAhmaNasarvamantrI
>
> ...

As to why these verses didn't make it to the BORI CE, you can read the explanation [here](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.485490/page/n565/mode/2up) (it's something to do with the verses not present in several manuscripts of Mahābhārata).